# SQLite C# Insert an unsigned integer store a negative number

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a this table

> CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (`Id`  NUMERIC NOT NULL,`UnsignedValue`    NUMERIC 
>   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)

I have to save a number as Id and an unsigned integer in the column 'UnsignedValue'.
My Insert using C#:

```
int id = 1;
uint myUnsignedValue = 3990427167;
using (IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = $@"INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, UnsignedValue) VALUES (@id, @value)";

    IDbDataParameter par = cmd.CreateParameter();
    par.ParameterName = "@id";
    par.Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);

    par = cmd.CreateParameter();
    par.ParameterName = "@value";
    par.Value = myUnsignedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The insert works but if I look with DB Browser for SQLite, **in that column I see a negative value**.
My concern is about I am using Dapper for mapping data source to my object model. The SELECt query gives exception because the value is too small for an uint type.

I checked the IDbParameter.DbType at runtime and it is UInt32 as expected.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**:

As suggested in the comments below I tried to use INTEGER column type instead of NUMERIC. But the result is the same.

I also noticed that the negative value stored is the same of an explicit Int32 cast to myUnsignedValue.

Comment: May be it's the wrong way to add a parameter. You should try the one where you explicity specify the type. Here your value is bigger than max int and get converted to negavive

Comment: Can you check that it's not just DB Browser that is mistaken? Use the command line and select the value, do you still get the negative value?

Comment: @DragandDrop even if I specify the parameter type the result is the same. By the way, my value is lower than [UInt32.MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.uint32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.8). So I still don't understand why it is converted negative.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tried: using the command line I get the same value I see in Db Browser. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I suspect SQLite isn't determining the value correctly - firstly it doesn't have unsigned integers - they're all signed 64bit values, secondly it determines size given the value and I think it's getting that wrong. Try declaring the value as a signed 64bit int and pass it. You may alwo wish to declare the column as being INTEGER explicitly rather than NUMERIC to rule out any affinity issues.

Comment: In your table schema try specifying an unsigned int rather than an unsigned numeric. That way the byte count remains the same in regards to unsigned data.

Comment: I tried to change the column type from NUMERIC to INTEGER. Same result. I noticed that the negative value I see is the same of a explicit Int32 cast on myUnsignedValue variable.

Comment: Sounds like SQLite is "correctly" determining the size of the parameter to be 32bit and *then* treating it as a signed value - because it doesn't have unsigned ones.

Comment: @motosubatsu you seems to be right. So the answer is "do not use uint"...right?

Comment: I'd try declaring it as an Int64

Comment: Yes, declaring variable as Int64 it store the right value, I still have problem with mapping...but it's another problem. If you post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect SQLite isn't determining the value correctly - firstly it doesn't have unsigned integers - they're all signed 64bit values, secondly it determines size given the value and I think it's getting that wrong.

From what you describe it sounds like SQLite is "correctly" determining the *size* of the parameter to be 32bit and then treating it as a signed value (because it doesn't have unsigned integers). So when the value is treated as a signed 32bit integer it gives you a negative value.

Declare the variable as an Int64 instead and it should correctly store the value.